# Given two intersecting lines and four circles all of which are tangent to two of the lines, how to choose one of the four circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the two intersecting lines, whose equations have the form $a_{1}x+b_{1}y+c_{1}=0$ and $a_{2}x+b_{2}y+c_{2}=0$, for example,

$$x+2y+3=0\\
2x-2y+4=0$$

and a radius $R$, there are four circles with radius $R$ that are tangent to both lines. For these lines in particular and a radius of $R=0.25$, the equations for the four circles are

$$(x+2.3827)^2 + (y+0.02914)^2 = 0.25^2$$
$$(x+2.284)^2 + (y+0.6375)^2 = 0.25^2$$
$$4(x+1.91129)^2 + (y+0.2648)^2 = 0.25^2$$
$$(x+2.75537)^2 + (y+0.401821)^2 = 0.25^2.$$

I have derived the equations of the centers of the circles $(c_{x}, c_{y})$ to be

$$ c_{y} = \frac{-a_{2}L_{1}R + a_{1}L_{2}R + a_{2}c_{1} - a_{1}c_{2}}{b_{2}a_{1}-a_{2}b_{1}}$$

$$c_{x} = \frac{L_{1}R - b_{1}c_{y}-c_{1}}{a_{1}},$$

where

$$L_{1}=\pm\sqrt{a_{1}^2+b_{1}^2}$$

$$L_{2}=\pm\sqrt{a_{2}^2+b_{2}^2}.$$

[Here is an image of the lines and the circles in the given example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTUag.png)

The problem I am having is that I would like to be able to know how to choose the signs of $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ so I know which circle i'm going to get before I compute the circles so I only have to compute one circle rather than compute all four and select one after the fact.